# Upload and download goes to different path when directly using tomcat server

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

Currently, my web application needs to upload and download files. When using tomcat through eclipse, it works fine. But the problem arises when I try to run from the tomcat server itself. Below are parts of my upload file code.

**upload.jsp**

```
function uploadAllFiles() {    
$("#button-confirm").attr("disabled", "disabled");
$("#button-cancel").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    var filesExist = true;
    $('.fileName').each(function(){
        if ($(this).get(0) == null || $(this).get(0) == "")
        {
            filesExist = false;
        }
    });
    //go here for upload
    if (filesExist)
    {
        if(!isAjaxUploadSupported()){ //IE fallback
            var iframe = document.createElement("<iframe name='upload_iframe_myFile' id='upload_iframe_myFile'>");
                iframe.setAttribute("width", "0");
            iframe.setAttribute("height", "0");
            iframe.setAttribute("border", "0");
            iframe.setAttribute("src","javascript:false;");
            iframe.style.display = "none";

            var form = document.createElement("form");
            form.setAttribute("target", "upload_iframe_myFile");
            form.setAttribute("action", "uploadFiles");
            form.setAttribute("method", "post");
            form.setAttribute("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
            form.setAttribute("encoding", "multipart/form-data");
            form.style.display = "none";

            $('.fileName').each(function(){
                form.appendChild($(this).get(0));
            });

            document.body.appendChild(form);
            document.body.appendChild(iframe);
            iframeIdmyFile = document.getElementById("upload_iframe_myFile");

            // Add event...
            var eventHandlermyFile = function () {
                if (iframeIdmyFile.detachEvent) 
                    iframeIdmyFile.detachEvent("onload", eventHandlermyFile);
                else 
                    iframeIdmyFile.removeEventListener("load", eventHandlermyFile, false);

                response = getIframeContentJSON(iframeIdmyFile);
                return;
            }

            if (iframeIdmyFile.addEventListener) 
                iframeIdmyFile.addEventListener("load", eventHandlermyFile, true);
            if (iframeIdmyFile.attachEvent) 
                iframeIdmyFile.attachEvent("onload", eventHandlermyFile);

            form.submit();
        }
        else
        {
            // Create a new FormData object.
            var formData = new FormData();

            $('.fileName').each(function(){
                var files = $(this).prop("files");
                for (var x = 0; x < files.length; x++)
                {
                    var file = files[x];
                    // Add the file to the request.
                    formData.append('files[]', file, file.name);
                }
            });

            var url = "uploadFiles";
            $.ajax({
               url: url,
               type: 'POST',
               data: formData,
               dataType: "json",
               cache: false,
               async: false,
               contentType: false,
               processData: false,
               success:function(result){

                }
            });
        }
    }

}

});
```

**FileLocationContextListener.java**

```
public class FileLocationContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {      
    ServletContext ctx = servletContextEvent.getServletContext();
    String relativePath = ctx.getInitParameter("upload.location");     

    File file = new File(relativePath);
    if(!file.exists()) file.mkdirs();
    System.out.println("File Directory created to be used for storing files" + relativePath);
    ctx.setAttribute("FILES_DIR_FILE_HRD", file);
    ctx.setAttribute("FILES_DIR_HRD", /*rootPath + File.separator + */relativePath);
}

public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    //do cleanup if needed
}
```

}

**web.xml**

```
  <context-param>
   <param-name>upload.location</param-name>
   <param-value>C:/Claim/Attachment/</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

Why does tomcat save the file in C:/Apache... directory when it is supposed to save it in **C:/Claim/Attachment/**? To avoid confusion, I will explain more. User can upload any file to the server. Then, the upload file supposedly save in  C:/Claim/Attachment/. After the file save there, there will be a url link for user to download. Obviously when user download it will saved to the C:/Download. But what I am trying to say is in order for the user to be able download the file, the path for the upload file should be the correct one. So, that user can download the file from the correct path. **Anyone that know what cause the problem?

Comment: I understand that you want to download to user `C:/Download`. Is it true?

Comment: Supposedly user can upload file and the file will be save to C:/Download. If user want to download the file, it will get from C:/Download. Unfortunately it save to catalina_home. Means it saves to C:/Apache..... And user also failed to download as the path is C:/Download

Comment: You can not save file to client defined location. For security purposes. When client click to download for example in chrome it downlods to user/downloads folder. It may be different for other browsers.

Comment: Its correct, if user download the file, it will goes to user/download folder.  But thats not what I need to solved. My main problem is when upload a file, it suppose to save file into a path. For example C:/upload/files. But it never go there. It goes to default path which is not what I want